# How do I delete the Postgresql 13 installed by MacPorts?

Tags: postgresql, macos, macports, postgresql-13

I tried installing Postgresql 13 on my new computer using MacPorts and have been completely unsuccessful getting anything to run, and not even sure if it is actually completely or properly installed, and I would like to delete all the Postgresql installed by MacPorts on my system.

The only directories for Postgres I have found are:

```
/opt/local/include
/opt/local/lib
/opt/local/share
```

nothing in:

```
/Library
```

This doesn't seem like the installation locations I have read anything about and I haven't found anything about uninstalling this from my system.

So, the question is, what do I do?

Do I just delete those directories and move forward with a different installation method, or look in other locations, or just leave it there and try to install Postgresql another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo port installed

sudo port uninstall postgresql13-server

. . .